# Use of power series in context of bernoulli differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

An exercise asked me to first show how to reduce $$x'=f(t)x+g(t)x^\alpha$$ to a linear differential equation $z'=(1-\alpha)(f(t)z+g(t))$. Then, as an example, it asked me to use this concept to solve the case $f(t)=-t, g(t)=t, \alpha=3$. So, I consider $$z'=2tz-2t,$$ 
and, thanks to a hint, let $$z(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n.$$

Why is this advantageous?

Now, I managed to show $a_1=0$, $a_2=a_0-1$, and $a_{n+1}=\frac{2a_{n-1}}{n+1}$, that is, $a_n=0$ for $n$ odd, and $a_n=\frac{a_0-1}{(n/2+1)!}$ for $n$ even. Am I wrong? The result is close to the sine power series, so, I have some doubts. And, if not, am I finished?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $z'=2\,t\,z-2\,t$ is linear. I am sure you have seen methods for solving it. One of them is to multiply by the integrating factor $e^{-t^2}$ to get
$$
\bigl(e^{-t^2}\,z\bigr)'=-2\,t\,e^{-t^2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, I got that, but why the hint then? I assumed the question should be solved via use of representation of $z(t)$ as a power series; is this not advantegeous?

Comment: Unless it was specifically asked, I do not see any particular advantage in this case. Take into account that even if you have the series solution for $z$, you still have to find $x$.